# Passbook IOS6 sends HTTP DELETE to Rails 3.0.3 server, No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, ios6, passbook

I get "No route matches" when Passbook, on iOS6, sends my server an HTTP DELETE route.

In config/routes.rb, the route looks like:

```
delete       "/v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_number" => "registrations#destroy"
```

and when I run "rake routes" I can see the route is there:

```
 DELETE /v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_number(.:format) {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"destroy"}
```

but when the route comes in to the Rails 3.0.3 development server as

```
Started DELETE "/v1/devices/515a5c955dcdd66f558e1b4041392bf3/registrations/pass.com.myserver.FreeDrink/11" for 192.168.0.22 at 2012-12-23 15:03:25 -0500
```

the rails server says:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/v1/devices/515a5c955dcdd66f558e1b4041392bf3/registrations/pass.com.myserver.FreeDrink/11"):
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

All the other routes, using HTTP GET and POST work fine.  This is the only route I'm having trouble with.  I know that some browsers don't send HTTP DELETE, only HTTP GET and HTTP POST, and rails puts something in the header to indicate that the request is a delete, but it is Passbook that is sending the HTTP DELETE request, so I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

I've also tried other flavors of the route in config/routes.rb such as:

match       "/v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_number" => "registrations#destroy", :via => :delete

and I've also tried using other controllers.

Any one know why Rails says that "No route matches" when the request is an HTTP DELETE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the delete route to work by using the route from this [post](https://github.com/xtremelabs/xl-passbook-ruby/blob/master/config/routes.rb)

```
 delete       "/v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_number" => "users#delete_pass", :constraints => { :pass_type_id => /[^\/]+/ }
```

which has the constraint added:

```
:constraints => { :pass_type_id => /[^\/]+/ }
```